# How to brought the activity infront when the outgoing call is going?

Tags: android, android-intent, telephonymanager

Let the question is i am using a broadcast receiver to listen the incoming or outgoing call. and i want if there is any incoming or outgoing call my activity brought in front or top of the UI of calling screen. I tried almost every solution like Thread priority and add flags to the intent but cant able to brought in front activity. please tell me solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure, why cant you call the main activity when the broadcast is active. But this will not good approach. While getting a call, the end user has to view the dial pad instead to view your activity.

Comment: I know but i want to do some task from that UI like a call record etc..

Comment: I can call the activity and it will be show me in the back of the calling screen.,,i need to brought in front whenever the call is OFF hook

Comment: Instead of doing what you said, try something like, when the call broadcast is on, activate the default recorder.So that whenever the call is live, it records the voice through background. and again receive the broadcast for call end. once this receiver is on, stop the recording intent. While doing this, no need to calling your activity in-front when the end user makes a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to handle phone call requests:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html